# How to remove the spacing behind a picker that used to be taken up by a carat?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I would like to remove the carat sign behind a picker in UWP
As such I followed this post -
[Xamarin.Forms UWP - How to hide or change color of Picker / ComboBox dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062349/xamarin-forms-uwp-how-to-hide-or-change-color-of-picker-combobox-dropdown-ar/47072708) - to remove the carat.

Now the carat is removed but the space is still being taken up causing the text to not display correctly (incomplete display):

[image]

I tried adjusting the margins but I still get the same bug. 
Any idea which part of the code in the link above am I supposed to adjust or if I am missing out some lines of code which could help remove this spacing that the carat used to occupy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting the `DropDownGlyph.Visibility` to collapsed, you also have to modify the `Grid` column, in which it is supposed to be to have zero width. You will find the following in the style:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The second column has hardcoded width of 32, which makes the "space" for the arrow to be there even if the arrow is not actually displayed. To remove it, just set the width to 0 or remove the column altogether:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: oh yes you are right. I tried to set it to 1 previously not sure why i thought it didnt work. perhaps the build didnt get build properly

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Happy coding :-) !