# How to remove/replace picker dropdown icon from Xamarin Forms UWP?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, combobox, xamarin.uwp

I am using Xamarin.Forms picker from PCL project but in case of Android and iOS the picker drop-down icon is not available and for UWP picker drop-down icon is available.

I got a solution that adds a picker drop-down image for Android and iOS platform (https://xamgirl.com/picker-with-right-side-icon-in-xamarin-forms/) and I need to use the same logic for UWP as well. So I need to hide the current drop-down icon from UWP picker(ComboBox) and update the icon with the custom image.

I would like to remove the drop-down icon from a picker in UWP As such I followed this post -([Xamarin.Forms UWP - How to hide or change color of Picker / ComboBox dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062349/xamarin-forms-uwp-how-to-hide-or-change-color-of-picker-combobox-dropdown-ar/47072708))

I don't want to write any code inside the platform-specific App.xaml file.
But I need to remove the icon from ***custom renderer class***, is there any way to do that?
Or I need to update that icon with the custom image from ***custom rendered class***.

Comment: Does the below answers works, and do you have any updates for this thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I don't want to write any code inside the platform-specific App.xaml file. But I need to remove the icon from custom renderer class,

For your requirement, you could make custom render for picker. and find the dropdown icon with visualtreeheler, then set it's  `Visibility` as `Collapsed` to remove it. Or give it specific graph to change it.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Picker), typeof(CustomPickerRender))]
namespace BindablePicker.UWP
{
    public class CustomPickerRender : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Loaded += Control_Loaded;

            }
        }

        private void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dropdown = MyFindChildByName(Control, "DropDownGlyph") as FontIcon;
            dropdown.Glyph = "\xE790";
          //dropdown.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public static DependencyObject MyFindChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
        {
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
                if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
                    return MyChild;

                var FindResult = MyFindChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
                if (FindResult != null)
                    return FindResult;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution though

```
<Frame Padding="10">
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyPicker}, Path=SelectedItem.Title}" />
                    <Image Source="downdownpng.png" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <Picker
                    x:Name="MyPicker"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemSource}" />
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
```

in your .cs

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyPicker.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Please check op's requirement, he want *But I need to remove the icon from **custom renderer** class*.